Read Page number from *.xbb file: errors when wrapped in a package file
extractbb is a command come with Tex Live, which can extract basic info of a pdf file. For example:
extractbb test.pdf

produce a file test.xbb with the info:
%%Title: test.pdf
%%Creator: extractbb 20240407
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 612 792
%%HiResBoundingBox: 0.000000 0.000000 612.000000 792.000000
%%PDFVersion: 1.5
%%Pages: 30
%%CreationDate: Wed Oct 23 00:11:36 2024

One interest is to get the page number from this file.
In the post How to read %%Pages:... from *.xbb file, David Carlisle's reply shows a nice solution.
I wrapped the solution in a macro \Enumber, so that we can easily change the name of *.xbb file. It works if I put the definition of \Enumber in the main .tex file, or a file loading by \input. But if I put the definition of \Enumber in a package file test.sty, I get an error.
The MWE is:

The test.sty:
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{test}[2024/01/01]

\def\Enumber#1{%
{\def\%##1: ##2@{\expandafter\xdef\csname ZZ##1\endcsname{##2}}%
\endlinechar`\@%
\catcode`\%=0 \sbox0{\input{#1}}}%
\ZZPages%
}


The main.tex:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{test} 
\begin{document}
\Enumber{test.xbb}
\end{document}



I get the error ! File ended while scanning use of \%. when compile the main.tex.
As it can give the right page number 30 if I put the definition of \Enumber in the main.tex, I thought it may be due to the Catcode change of delimiters :  and/or @ in the definition of the macro \%. However, the Catcode of : and @ should always being 12; and I can remove the space   for simplicity. But even I do that, I still get the same error message.


\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{test}[2024/01/01]

\def\Enumber#1{%
{\def\%##1: ##2+{\expandafter\xdef\csname ZZ##1\endcsname{##2}}%
\endlinechar`\+%
\catcode`\%=0 \sbox0{\input{#1}}}%
\ZZPages%
}

You need to put the same character at the end of each line as you use in the delimited argument. I use catcode 12 + here.
In your version you were making a delimited argument with a catcode 11 @ but using it in the main document so getting a catcode 12 @ at the end of each line.

May I ask why @ get catcode 12 in the main document but 11 at *.sty?As I know, we should use \makeatletter to change it's Catcode to 12 in the main document? I did not do this in the main document but still works. My another question is, does the content imported by macro \input will get a different Catcodes, or they are set as default Catcodes?

@XLeo makeatletter makes @ catcode 11. @ is 11 in sty files so it can be part of command names and 12 in documents so it can not.  \input doesn't itself change the catcodes, but in the code here % is a comment in the macro definition but the escape character (like \  in the input document)
